# bcp output to UTF-8 not working in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bcp

I have SQL Server 2016.
I'm trying to upload to Google Big Query (GCP).
I am using BCP to output the file to CSV, however, in spite of the following code:

```
BCP \"{}\" queryout \"{}\" -t~ -U xxx -P xxx -S "localhost" -T -r 0x0a -c -C65001
```

I'm still getting UTF-8 read errors.

I was told 65001 was a valid code page for UTF-8, and should work for the output.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017 Versions prior to version 13 ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can import UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I have 13.0.5081.1.  should that not support it?

Comment: I'm using version 14.0.2037.2 and it doesn't work either, do you got any news on this topic?